# C++ largest power of 2 <= n

Tags: c++

How do I calculate the largest power of two <= some number n?

Right now I am using floor(log(n)/log(2)+.05) but it doesn't seem to be reliable for all n. Is there anything a little cleaner / not at the mercy of rounding errors?

Comment: Is n an integer or floating point value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure which integral type you're targeting, so at the behest of trying to cover them all...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value,T>::type fn(T N)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    return T(1) << static_cast<T>(std::floor(std::log2(N)));
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << fn(4095) << std::endl;
    std::cout << fn(4096) << std::endl;
    std::cout << fn(4097) << std::endl;
    std::cout << fn(281474976710655) << std::endl;
    std::cout << fn(281474976710656) << std::endl;
    std::cout << fn(281474976710657) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type fn(T) [T = int]
2048
typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type fn(T) [T = int]
4096
typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type fn(T) [T = int]
4096
typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type fn(T) [T = long]
140737488355328
typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type fn(T) [T = long]
281474976710656
typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type fn(T) [T = long]
281474976710656
```

Comment: Is there a way to just get the exponent, not the whole power?

Comment: @user2175923 Take out the shift. `return static_cast<T>(std::floor(std::log2(N)));`

Comment: I don't think the question warrants the complexity of the answer (in particular SFINAE), specially considering that the implementation need not provide overloads of `log2` that take integral types so the different overloads may generate multiple versions of the same code. Other than that, there are algorithms designed for this solution that will be more efficient.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Agreed. It would be best (IMHO)
 for the answer to use the faster algorithms for general 32-bit integers, and then expand on a template approach and specialization for different word sizes to improve performance.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I didn't expect this to be marked as the answer. I only provided it to show one way of accomplishing the requested task. Worse, since it is accepted I can't drop it either. Any suggestions?

Comment: @WhozCraig: No, it is up to the OP to accept or reject. I only pointed out that there are better approaches that could have been approved. Less complexity, more efficient code. At any rate I did learn (did not know of `std::log2`, don't really do math in my projects) and others will, so it is deserved :)

Answer (score 4):

I assume that the number is unsigned. You can use the knowledge of the binary representation.

That number will be the number with 1 at same MSB position and with all zero.

Following loop will help you.

```
do {
    y = x;
    x = x&(x-1);
}while(x);
return y;
```

where `x` is the original number and the `y` is the result.

Branch free code is given below.

```
unsigned flp2(unsigned x) {
  x = x| (x>>1);
  x = x| (x>>2);
  x = x| (x>>4);
  x = x| (x>>8);
  x = x| (x>>16);
return x - (x>>1);
}
```

or (counting on loop unrolling, which all modern compilers can do)

```
unsigned log2(unsigned x)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::digits; i*=2)
     x |= (x>>i);
  return x - (x>>1);
}
```

Source: Hacker's Delight.

Comment: The first example has the benefit of being correct for 64 bits integers. It looks like it's bad for `(1<<N) - 1`. E.g. 0xF -> 0xE -> 0xC -> 0x8 -> 0x0 : 4 steps to clear 4 bits. It is faster for 1<<N, though. The second example could be made portable with template meta-programming and `std::numeric_limits<unsigned>`

Comment: Actually you don't need templates if you just need it for `unsigned`.

Answer (score 1):

In binary (assuming you have an integral type) the largest power of 2 is the Most Significant Bit

There are several ways to calculate this efficiently

the most efficent is to use a built-in that uses machine code that can execute in one cycle

the least efficient is to loop through removing the lowest bit

Here is one I like if you can't use built-ins:

```
unsigned int v;  // 32-bit value to find the log2 of 
const unsigned int b[] = {0x2, 0xC, 0xF0, 0xFF00, 0xFFFF0000};
const unsigned int S[] = {1, 2, 4, 8, 16};
int i;

register unsigned int r = 0; // result of log2(v) will go here
for (i = 4; i >= 0; i--) // unroll for speed...
{
  if (v & b[i])
  {
    v >>= S[i];
    r |= S[i];
  } 
}
```

you can find more like this at: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogLookup

Comment: what's a builtin for this?

Comment: @user2175923 in GNU -- Built-in Function: `int __builtin_clz (unsigned int x)`
more here - http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html
Windows has its own as do other compilers - but then you have to have a port for each compiler (and default to a non builtin)

Comment: Mind you, if the code is obvious enough (e.g. dbasic's answer), there is a reasonable chance that the optimizer will recognize it and use the best implementation anyway. Distrust any answer with manual loop unrolling or `register` keyword, as that assumes outdated compilers.

Comment: @MSalters I would not count on the compiler figuring to remove a call to log2 or to convert to arrays.   Nor is branchless necessarily faster.    Older algorythms that use register can still be faster.  Unfortunately even builtins on some architetures can call slow microcode.  Testing is still the only way to tell and only then for that code base on that architecture with that compiler version.

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum: Loop unrolling indeed can be slower. Which is why I said to distrust manual loop unrolling. Leave it to a compiler which knows. As for "Older algorithms using `register`", they are not faster. Todays compilers flat out ignore the keyword. AFAIK there's not a single known case left where it could provide a benefit.

Comment: @MSalters dbasics solution is mostly an unroll of the one I posted.  And what I meant is that an algo that used register, if you ignore the register usage,  may still be a good algo.  Its usage of register not withstanding

Answer (score 0):

This test worked for 32 bit signed int where ***best*** is assigned the closest power of 2 to the candidate value, ***x*** in the domain of 4 to ~2 billion:

```
for (int x = 4; x < (1<<31)-1; x++)
{
    int best = (int)(log((double)x)/log(2.0));

    int test = (int)pow((double)2, best);

    if (test > x || (test*2 <= x && test*2 > 0)) // test*2 < 0 when very large
        break; // fail
}
```